# Custom 'order by' with some preferent rows?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following data in a table

```
pk | i | val
------------
1  | 0 | hi
2  | 3 | good bye
3  | 4 | good day
5  | 6 | howdy
```

If I `select * from mytable ORDER BY val`, I will get the order 2, 3, 1, 5.

But what if I want to give "preference" to two particular rows before the rest of normally-ordered rows? Let's say val=hi,good bye.

In other words, how would I write the SQL query to be able to return 1,5,2,3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
from table1
order by case when val in ('hi', 'howdy') then 0 else 1 end, val
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/37097/1)</kbd>**

or

```
select *
from table1
order by
    case val
        when 'howdy' then 0
        when 'hi' then 1
        else 2
    end, val
```

or (easier to add new variables)

```
select *
from table1
order by
    case val
        when 'howdy' then 2
        when 'hi' then 1
        else 0
    end desc, val
```

Comment: and what if I want to put howdy before hi?

Comment: @knocte `then 0` becomes `then val = 'hi'`